# Export PyroCMS to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, pyrocms

Pyrocms has a WordPress importer, but I haven't found a good way to export to WordPress. Any ideas, other than writing a parser myself for the existing pyrocms export?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the PyroCMS RSS feed with the Wordpress RSS importer in Tools>>Import

Or make a new page template to export XML from Pyro and then convert that to the Wordpress WXR format.